# How to select a specific row from some same class name of a table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

I have a `Campaign` data table in my Laravel webpage. I want to change the status of any `campaign` by clicking button from `action` column using AJAX.

[campaign data table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COYTg.jpg)

I want while I clicked `inactive` button in `action` column that campaign `status` should be changed into `active` from `inactive` instantly and only that row will be changed and no other row will be affected. That's why I am using AJAX.

But in my case while I clicked that `inactive` button all other status removed and only one status show like below image.

[image after clicking action button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZ8Q7.jpg)

But I want to only change status of that specific row.

**datatable html**

```
 <td id="status_td">
        @if($campaign->status == 'active' && $campaign->finalized == 0)
          <span class="status label label-success">{{trans('misc.active')}}</span>
        @elseif($campaign->status == 'pending' && $campaign->finalized == 0)
          <span class="status label label-warning">{{trans('admin.pending')}}</span>
        @elseif($campaign->status == 'inactive' && $campaign->finalized == 0)
           <span class="status label label-danger">Inactive</span>
        @else
           <span class="status label label-default">{{trans('misc.finalized')}}</span>
        @endif
  </td>
  <td> 
      <a href="{{ url('panel/admin/campaigns/edit', $campaign->id) }}" class="btn btn-success btn-xs padding-btn">
           <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
      </a>
      @if($campaign->status == 'active' && $campaign->finalized == 0)
         <button id="" class="status_change_inactive label label-danger" value="{{ $campaign->id }}">Inactive</button>
      @elseif($campaign->status == 'inactive' && $campaign->finalized == 0)
         <button id="" class="status_change_active label label-success" value="{{ $campaign->id }}">Active</button>
      @endif
  </td>
```

**AJAX script**

```
$( ".status_change_inactive" ).click(function() {
  var id = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
      type:'GET',
      url:"{{ url('ajax/status_change_inactive') }}",
      data:{campaign_id : id},
      success:function(data) {

        $('#status_td span').remove();

        trHTML = '<span class="status label label-danger">Inactive</span>';

        $('#status_td').append(trHTML);
     }
  });

});
```

How can I do that ? Anybody Help Please ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have same id for the `td` since you have multiple rows

I hope this would help you

`<td id="status_td{{$campaign->id}}">`

```
$( ".status_change_inactive" ).click(function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:"{{ url('ajax/status_change_inactive') }}",
        data:{campaign_id : id},
        success:function(data) {
            $('#status_td'+id+' span').remove();
            trHTML = '<span class="status label label-danger">Inactive</span>';
            $('#status_td'+id).append(trHTML);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#status_td span')` is a general selector with no reference to the clicked button. You need to define a refrence to the clicked button. For example I find `targetTD` as previous TD which is parent of clicked button and do other stuffs to `targetTD`

```
$( ".status_change_inactive" ).click(function() {
  var id = $(this).val();
  //This line is what you need:
  var targetTD= $(this).parent().prev("td");

  $.ajax({
      type:'GET',
      url:"{{ url('ajax/status_change_inactive') }}",
      data:{campaign_id : id},
      success:function(data) {

        targetTD.find("span").remove();

        trHTML = '<span class="status label label-danger">Inactive</span>';

        targetTD.append(trHTML);
     }
  });

});
```

**FootNote:** working with ID (#status_td) is wrong here as you have multiple rows with same ID.

**Edit:** if there are more TD between those two, you can set a **specialClass** on the target TD and find it like this

```
var targetTD= $(this).closest('tr').find('.specialClass')
```

Comment: .....there are more `<td></td>` between these two `td`....so can't use `var targetTD= $(this).parent().prev("td");`....hope so u get it bro...any other solution brother?

Comment: Yes please check the Edit at the end of answer. @Raff

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat closer to your need

```js
$(".action").on("click", function() {

  if ($(this).closest('td').prev().text() == "Active") {
    $(this).closest('td').prev().text("Inctive")
  } else {
    $(this).closest('td').prev().text("Active")
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <td>Status</td>
      <td class="action">Action</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>john@example.com</td>
      <td>Inactive</td>
      <td class="action"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>Moe</td>
      <td>mary@example.com</td>
      <td>Inactive</td>
      <td class="action"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>July</td>
      <td>Dooley</td>
      <td>july@example.com</td>
      <td>Inactive</td>
      <td class="action"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```